# Android - Connecting to localhost URL from mobile (3g/4g) network

Tags: android, server, localhost, 3g, 4g

I am making an app that sends user data to a javascript server hosted locally. It sends the data fine when my phone is on WiFi, but it gives an error ('failed to connect to: "/MY_LOCAL_IP"("PORT")) when I turn off WiFi. Is it even possible to connect to my local ip when on 3g/4g?

Answer (score 0):

when your phone is on WiFi it's working fine because your mobile and your PC connected to the same network.but when you will connect your mobile to 3g/4g your mobile will connect to the different network and you can't access localhost javascript server address.

Comment: Thank you Asim! I now host my server online instead off on localhost and it works fine.